# Change color plot3d (rgl) at R notebook

Tags: r, rgl, rnotebook, plot3d

I'm trying to change the color using a specific column (characters) with `plot3d` (rgl), but it don't change color and just show white spheres. I used `col=as.numeric()` because saw a example with this. The only message I get is

> NAs introduced by coercion.

I'm working with R notebook.

```
library("rgl")
with(inventory_wop,
plot3d(dbh1.a,ht,wd, 
xlab = "Diameter",
ylab="Height",
zlab="Wood density",
type="s",
size = 0.5,
col=as.numeric(site)))

rglwidget()
```

Comment: You need to include your dataset.  I'm guessing that `site` is a character column in `inventory_wop`, and `as.numeric(site)` returns `NA`, because the characters don't form numbers.  You may need to convert to a factor first.

Comment: you could try `col=factor(site)`